# Admin order grid: Column 'store_name' in where clause is ambiguous when filtering by store

Tags: magento-1.9, sql, order-grid

I am getting this error when trying to filter the sales grid by store. I can fix this error by altering `app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\Grid.php`and replacing

```
if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
    $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased From (Store)'),
        'index'     => 'store_id',
        'type'      => 'store',
        'store_view'=> true,
        'display_deleted' => true,
    )); }
```

with

```
if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
    $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased From (Store)'),
        'index'     => 'main_table.store_id',
        'type'      => 'store',
        'store_view'=> true,
        'display_deleted' => true,
    ));
}
```

However, I would like to understand why this is happening in the first place.
Also if I edit Grid.php like that, all my store view names will include [deleted] - this I don't understand at all...

Comment: I still don't know why this is happening but if I edit Grid.php and instead of changing the 'index' line add this line 'filter_index' => 'main_table.store_id', it will work.

Comment: check grid is overriding some other extensions or not